# Split a polygon into segments

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I have a polygon in Illustrator (shown below).  How can I split it into separate line segments at every anchor point AND intersection with another line?

Basically I'm trying to recreate the "Pemrose Triangle" [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0yIS.gif). I plan on animating it, so that is why I need things in separate segments.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pathfinder's Outline command will split your artwork in to its component line segments, essentially breaking apart you paths at any intersection.

It *won't* break apart at *every* anchor point so you will need to manually cut any corner that isn't an intersection (use the Scissors Tool <kbd>C</kbd>), but in this specific case you should only need to cut the vertices of the outermost triangle.

[image]